# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I wrote some code to test my configuration of Hibernate. But I come across an error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:61)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
```

My file structure is like below:

```
src
---test
-------Test.java(with main function)
-------User.java
-------User.hbm.xml
----hibernate.cfg.xml
```

This is not a web application, it's just an ordinary java project. The hibernate.cfg.xml is like below:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Configure MySQL -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.URL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mags</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">bysjysf</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Mapping Files -->
        <mapping resource="test/User.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The code in main function is like below:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");         
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
    StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();                   
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println(session);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    User user = new User();
    user.setPassword("aaaa");
    user.setUsername("ysf");
    user.setAuthority(1);
    session.save(user);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

According the error message, the error occurred in
`Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();`

I am a new user for Hibernate, and I have checked my configuration file many times. Could anyone help to figure out what the problem is? Thanks!

The Hibernate version is 4.3.5

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The hibernate property names in the configuration file are case sensitive.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.URL">
```

should be

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
```