# Issue migrating to JBOSS 6.2 - application must supply JDBC connection

Tags: java, jboss

I have an application that was working ok on JBOSS 6.0.

Then I started using 6.2 by:

- copying the app .war file
- changing myy jboss_home env var
- copying the standalone.xml file from the 6.0 to the 6.2

I cannot start the app on the JBOSS 6.2. See server log below. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

```
C:\Users\tfirmino\Desktop>cd C:\jboss-eap-6.2\bin

C:\jboss-eap-6.2\bin>standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.3-preview20130601)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-eap-6.2

  JAVA: C:\jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -D
jboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

11:00:53,201 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
11:00:53,342 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
11:00:53,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) sta
rting
11:00:55,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting fa
iled deployment tar.war
11:00:55,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found tar.war in
 deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called tar.war.dodeploy
11:00:55,142 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
11:00:55,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using soc
ket-binding (management-http)
11:00:55,142 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
11:00:55,158 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.18.GA-redhat-1
11:00:55,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsy
stem
11:00:55,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinis
pan subsystem.
11:00:55,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
11:00:55,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:00:55,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011906: Activating OSGi Subsystem
11:00:55,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP2-red
hat-1
11:00:55,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Exten
sion
11:00:55,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:00:55,236 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implemen
tations: [main, 1.2]
11:00:55,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mai
l/Default]
11:00:55,283 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJac
amar 1.0.23.Final-redhat-1)
11:00:55,283 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS014613: Operatio
n ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "rdbthin.jar")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [oracle.rdb]"
11:00:55,299 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS014613: Operatio
n ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.oracle.db]"
11:00:55,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deployi
ng JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:00:55,393 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS014613: Operatio
n ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "OracleJDBCDriver")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.oracle.ojdbc6]"
11:00:55,533 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : ht
tp-/127.0.0.1:8080
11:00:55,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data sourc
e [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:00:55,549 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/1
27.0.0.1:8080
11:00:55,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
11:00:55,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeplo
ymentService for directory C:\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\deployments
11:00:55,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
11:00:55,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "tar.war
" (runtime-name: "tar.war")
11:00:55,643 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - S
tack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final-redhat-1
11:00:55,894 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for APP_SOURCE
11:00:56,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 't
ar.war#APP_SOURCE'
11:00:56,097 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HCANN000001: Hibernate C
ommons Annotations {4.0.1.Final-redhat-2}
11:00:56,113 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.SP1-redhat
-3}
11:00:56,113 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not
 found
11:00:56,113 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name :
 javassist
11:00:56,128 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000204: Processing Persist
enceUnitInfo [
        name: APP_SOURCE
        ...]
11:00:56,316 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (ServerService Thread P
ool -- 52) HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections

11:00:56,332 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hiber
nate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
11:00:56,332 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000422: D
isabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
11:00:56,535 WARN  [org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000038: Composite-id class doe
s not override equals(): myApp.entity.StudentUnitAuditPK
11:00:56,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool --
 52) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
11:00:56,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH00039
7: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:00:56,582 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HV000001: Hibernate
 Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
11:00:56,989 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000229: Running sch
ema validator
11:00:56,989 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000102: Fetching da
tabase metadata
11:00:56,989 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) MSC000001: Failed to start service jbo
ss.persistenceunit."tar.war#APP_SOURCE": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."tar.war#APP_SOURCE": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103) [jboss-as-jpa-
7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-r
edhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSupplied
ConnectionProviderImpl.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConne
ctionHelper.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1794)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServic
eImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-
jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7
.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        ... 4 more

11:00:59,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "tar.war" (runtime-name
: "tar.war")
11:00:59,447 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.OracleJDBCDriver (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasou
rces/ESS_SCIDS, service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/ldCommonds-u, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/
datasources/ldCommonds, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/ESS_SCIDS, JBAS014799: ... and 7 more ]
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."tar.war#APP_SOURCE": org.jboss.msc.servic
e.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."tar.war#APP_SOURCE": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The applic
ation must supply JDBC connections

11:00:59,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127
.0.0.1:9990/management
11:00:59,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:00:59,463 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) sta
rted (with errors) in 6544ms - Started 173 of 282 services (24 services failed or missing dependencies, 79 services are
passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with your hibernate configuration? Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222632/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-the-application-must-supply-jdbc-connec), it seems like the error might be related to some of your configuration, if you post some of your code and structure we can figure out what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your JBossEAP 6.0 system had a custom module containing the Oracle JDBC driver.

You also need to migrate that into the new server.

Additionally, it's generally a bad idea to migrate whole standalone.xml files forward into new versions of JBossAS/Wildfly. A better idea is to write a CLI script that does the configuration and use that to configure each new environment.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I added the module for the driver and got hid of that error. I also returned the original standalone.xml and put the information I needed, instead of cutting/past from JBOSS 6 to JBOSS 6.2 but the original error I mentioned on this post still persists... It still complains the app must supply JDBC connection...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

> 11:00:55,393 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS014613: Operatio n ("add")
>   failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("jdbc-driver" => "OracleJDBCDriver") ]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.oracle.ojdbc6]"

It seems like you have an Oracle JDBC module which is missing or failing.

Comment: Thanks Evandro, I added the module for the driver and got hid of that error, but the original error I mentioned on this post still persists... It stil complains the app must supply JDBC connection...

Comment: Could you please update your question with the current log? Just to make sure we work on the same log as you.